# My Sql Query to find top 3 retailerID on rScore for each userID

Tags: mysql

[image: Table structure]

I have to select userID and productID of top 3 retailerID based on rScore for each userID

I need my sql query to get result like 3rd table from first and second table.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service, what have you tried? Have you looked at the [greatest-n-per-group] tag?

Comment: Yes i have tried. But i have experience only in MS SQL. I'm trying best to find. That's y posted here.